# Animating LinearGradientBrush Color in Code-Behind

Tags: silverlight, animation, silverlight-3.0, coloranimation

I am playing a bit with trying to animate a LinearGradientBrush (lgb) in a Silverlight app.  I have the following code in the constructor for my Page:

```
    for (int stops = 0; stops < numStops; stops++)
    {
        ColorAnimation animation = new ColorAnimation();
        animation.To =
            Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)rnd.Next(256), (byte)rnd.Next(256), (byte)rnd.Next(256));
        animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, lgb);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation,
            new PropertyPath("GradientStops[" + stops.ToString() + "].Color"));
        Storyboard story = new Storyboard();
        story.Children.Add(animation);
        story.Begin();
    }
```

It compiles and runs, but doesn't change the color.  I just don't see what I'm doing incorrectly.

Thanks,
wTs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code works fine under Silverlight 4 and in Windows Phone 7 (WP7 is pretty much Silverlight 3).  My guess is if I build an isolated app for SL3 it would work there too.

The only thing missing from your code is how `lgb` is aquired in the first place?  Are you sure its the same instance that is actually being used in your UI.

For example, I just added the brush to my LayoutRoot Grid like this:-

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
```

Then in code I assign lgb with:-

```
LinearGradientBrush lgb = (LinearGradientBrush)LayoutRoot.Background;
```

Comment: I will have to write a test app in both 3 and 4 "when I have time", and get back to you...

Comment: And, yes, lgb is the background of the LayoutRoot grid, set in code just before the attempt at animation.